# express is rewriting my 'Content-Type' header from 'applicaiton/json' to 'text/plain'

Tags: json, node.js, express, content-type

I have an app using latest express 3.x (3.18.3) that returns some JSON data. I am setting the content-type header as follows:

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json')
```

but I am noticing that in the returned response the 'content-type' header is set to 'text/plain' ??

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that IF you have used the `express-json` then when you call `res.send` this module - by design - will check whether the request has the `accept: 'application/json' header set, and if not it will rewrite your content-type response header to 'text/plain' !

**So two easy solutions:**

1. If you can control the client is to set the accept header of the HTTP request.
2. Don't use express-json unless you want this behaviour

The code that rewrites the header in the `express-json` package version 1.0.0:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { module.exports = function () {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        var json = res.json;
        res.json = function () {
            if (!req.headers.accept || req.headers.accept.indexOf('application/json') === -1) {
                res.contentType('text/plain');
            }
            json.apply(res, arguments);
        };
        next();
    };
};
```

This is called from directly from `res.send` function in the `object` case of the switch block, IFF you have loaded `express-json`

Comment: i am face same kind of problem in expressjs 4.x. my error is {"success":false,"details":{"status":"ERROR","result":{"message":"Cannot read property 'name' of null","stack":["TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null","    at /home/amtex/Documents/projects/test_case/mobile_apis/output/util/user-util.js:73:13","    at newTickHandler (/home/amtex/Documents/projects/test_case/mobile_apis/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:234:18)","    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)","    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)"]}},"data":null}

Comment: if it wasn't for your comment, it would take me hours to debug what is going on. Yes we have that many middlewares in our monolithic app. Bless you @zayquan